# sbt shading two versions of a dependency

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, http4s, fatjar

When I run my tests I see the following error:

```
Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: fs2.Stream$.bracket(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function1;Lscala/Function1;)Lfs2/internal/FreeC;
```

I first made sure my build file was cleaned up by [explicitly declaring transitive dependencies](https://github.com/cb372/sbt-explicit-dependencies#finding-accidental-use-of-transitive-dependencies) and by removing [unused dependencies](https://github.com/cb372/sbt-explicit-dependencies#finding-unnecessary-dependencies) to produce the following build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
organization := "com.example "

lazy val lambdas = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core"   % "1.4.0",
    libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "1.0.0",

    libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-core"    % "0.10.0",
    libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.10.0",
    libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-parser"  % "0.10.0", 
    libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-fs2"     % "0.10.0",

    libraryDependencies += "co.fs2" %% "fs2-core" % "1.0.0",
    libraryDependencies += "co.fs2" %% "fs2-io"   % "0.10.0",

    libraryDependencies += "org.http4s" %% "http4s-circe"  % "0.18.0",
    libraryDependencies += "org.http4s" %% "http4s-client" % "0.18.0",
    libraryDependencies += "org.http4s" %% "http4s-core"   % "0.18.0",

    libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3",

    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.2.0",
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core"    % "1.11.422",
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3"      % "1.11.422",

    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest"  %% "scalatest"  % "3.0.5"  % "test",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0" % "test",

    libraryDependencies += "io.findify" %% "s3mock" % "0.2.4" % "test"
  )
```

Everything compiles and one of my two tests pass. The other fails with the error above. Here's the output of sbt evicted:

```
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * co.fs2:fs2-core_2.12:1.0.0 is selected over 0.10.0
[warn]      +- io.circe:circe-fs2_2.12:0.10.0                     (depends on 1.0.0)
[warn]      +- com.example:lambdas_2.12:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT             (depends on 1.0.0)
[warn]      +- co.fs2:fs2-scodec_2.12:0.10.0                      (depends on 0.10.0)
[warn]      +- org.http4s:jawn-fs2_2.12:0.12.0                    (depends on 0.10.0)
[warn]      +- co.fs2:fs2-io_2.12:0.10.0                          (depends on 0.10.0)
[warn]  * org.typelevel:cats-effect_2.12:1.0.0 is selected over 0.8
[warn]      +- co.fs2:fs2-core_2.12:1.0.0                         (depends on 1.0.0)
[warn]      +- com.example:lambdas_2.12:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT             (depends on 1.0.0)
[warn]      +- org.http4s:http4s-core_2.12:0.18.0                 (depends on 0.8)
[warn]  * org.typelevel:cats-core_2.12:1.4.0 is selected over {1.0.1, 1.3.1}
[warn]      +- io.circe:circe-core_2.12:0.10.0 ()                 (depends on 1.4.0)
[warn]      +- co.fs2:fs2-core_2.12:1.0.0                         (depends on 1.4.0)
[warn]      +- org.typelevel:cats-effect_2.12:1.0.0               (depends on 1.3.1)
[warn]      +- com.example:lambdas_2.12:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT             (depends on 1.3.1)
[warn]      +- org.http4s:http4s-core_2.12:0.18.0                 (depends on 1.0.1)
[warn]  * io.circe:circe-jawn_2.12:0.10.0 is selected over 0.9.1
[warn]      +- io.circe:circe-parser_2.12:0.10.0 ()               (depends on 0.10.0)
[warn]      +- io.circe:circe-fs2_2.12:0.10.0                     (depends on 0.10.0)
[warn]      +- org.http4s:http4s-circe_2.12:0.18.0                (depends on 0.9.1)
[warn]  * org.spire-math:jawn-parser_2.12:0.13.0 is selected over 0.11.0
[warn]      +- io.circe:circe-jawn_2.12:0.10.0 ()                 (depends on 0.13.0)
[warn]      +- org.http4s:jawn-fs2_2.12:0.12.0                    (depends on 0.11.0)
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Here are other depedency conflicts that were resolved:
[info]  * commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is selected over 1.2
[info]      +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.422           (depends on 1.1.3)
[info]      +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5         (depends on 1.2)
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Nov 28, 2018 12:56:33 PM
```

From using [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) it looks like I will legitimately need two versions of fs2-core: `1.0.0` and `0.10.0`.

This is my attempt at using [sbt-assembly shading](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) to handle the evictions by renaming the old version of fs2 in the http4s library that needs it. Nothing is actually compiling with this build file so I'm guessing there are multiple problems with the way I have things set up.

```
//build properties
//sbt.version=1.1.2

//assembly.sbt
//addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.8")

scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
organization := "com.example"

lazy val fatJar = project
  .enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core"   % "1.4.0",
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "1.0.0",

      "io.circe" %% "circe-core"    % "0.10.0",
      "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.10.0",
      "io.circe" %% "circe-parser"  % "0.10.0",
      "io.circe" %% "circe-fs2"     % "0.10.0",

      "co.fs2" %% "fs2-core" % "1.0.0",
      "co.fs2" %% "fs2-io"   % "0.10.0",

      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-circe"  % "0.18.0",
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-client" % "0.18.0",
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-core"   % "0.18.0",

      "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3",

      "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.2.0",
      "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core"    % "1.11.422",
      "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3"      % "1.11.422",

      "org.scalatest"  %% "scalatest"  % "3.0.5"  % "test",
      "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0" % "test",

      "io.findify" %% "s3mock" % "0.2.4" % "test"),

    assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
      ShadeRule.rename("co.fs2.**" -> "old_fs2.@1")
        .inLibrary("org.http4s" %% "http4s-circe" % "0.18.0")
        .inLibrary("org.http4s" %% "http4s-core"  % "0.18.0")
    )
  )

lazy val kraken_shaded = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "kraken-shaded",
    packageBin in Compile := (assembly in (fatJar, Compile)).value
```

Comment: It definitely has breaking changes. I was hoping to figure out how to include both, but shade the usage inside the http4s package so hits fs2 v0.10.0 while the rest of the project uses v1.0.0.

Comment: Ahh. Good point. Shading might work if http4s never exposed streams in their interface ....but of course that's not how that package works. I guess my options are to use a different http library until http4s 0.20.0 is out or to downgrade all my other dependencies until they only need fs2 0.10.0. Both are rather unfortunate options.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez if you want to drop an answer summarizing the comments I'll mark it as correct. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in neither **http4s** nor in **fs2**, but I believe that the `1.0.x` version of **fs2** introduces breaking changes.
And, as you can see [*here*](https://http4s.org/versions/), **http4s** `0.18.x` is built against **fs2** `0.10.x`.
Thus, I don't believe you can make them work together.

You may think in shading the `0.10.x` version of **fs2** for **http4s** and use the `1.0.x` version in your project...
But, I don't think that's even possible, unless you never use a *Stream* created by **http4s** nor you pass the *Stream* to **http4s** - and that is definitely not way it works.

Nevertheless, you may use [**http4s** `0.20.x`](https://http4s.org/v0.20/).
Right now it is a *Milestone*, so you can expect changes before it becomes stable - but it might work for now, if you don't want to downgrade to **fs2** `0.10.x`.